# What is the best way to add data and upload files to Rest api

Tags: ios, json, swift, rest, file-upload

My iOS application allows a user to submit a complaint to an online REST API with the following parameters:

**Data Fields**: such as name, phone number, ...

**Voice**: recorded from microphone

**Image/Video**: selected from photo gallery

1- how can i do that with swift?

2- how to get back an ID field from the server after submission?

3- how to manage an upload progress for the voice and media files?

Regards

Comment: You can use alamofire https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire

Comment: Learn `NSURLSession`. One of many tutorials can be found [here](https://www.raywenderlich.com/110458/nsurlsession-tutorial-getting-started).

Comment: i think [this tutorial](http://swiftdeveloperblog.com/send-http-post-request-example-using-swift-and-php/) is more simple to understand, but still need to handle the progress feedback..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After few weeks working hardly on it, here is my experience using Swift 3.1 which is run smoothly:

```
    //use POSTMAN plugin in Chrome browser to get the read header for your API (optional):
    let headers = [
        "cache-control": "no-cache",
        "postman-token": "00000000-1111-2222-3333-444444444"]

    //this is the important part:
    let strQuery: String = "mobileNo=" + txtMobileNB.text! + "&fullname=" + txtName.text!

    let request = try? NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: "http://service.website.com/apiname/?" + strQuery)! as URL,
                                          cachePolicy: .useProtocolCachePolicy,
                                          timeoutInterval: 10.0)
    request?.httpMethod = "POST"
    request?.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers

    if request != nil {

        let session = URLSession.shared
        let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: request! as URLRequest) {data,response,error in

            if let content = data
            {
                let responseData = String(data: content, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)

                //feedback from server:
                print(responseData)

                //call success function:
                self.showDone()
            } else {

                //call error function:
                self.showWrong()
            }

        }
        dataTask.resume()

    } else {
        //call error function:
        self.showWrong()
    }
```

Regarding the other part "how to upload", i've found [this framework](https://github.com/Constantine-Fry/rebekka) is a good one (called [rebekka](https://github.com/Constantine-Fry/rebekka)) to start your upload project through iOS apps.

hope this helps someone :)